# Lyx doesn't display matrix correctly

Tags: pdftex, lyx, matrices

I have tried to insert following LaTeX code for matrix in Lyx:

```
$u_{L}(k) = \sqrt{E}\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$.
```

In all LaTeX-based sites this code is displayed correctly, but Lyx have disappointed me: pdf-viewer Adobe Reader (which displayed all before that) shows that:

[image: An illustration to the problem]

The question: how to force Lyx to convert LaTeX code for matrices correctly?

Comment: have you loaded the `amsmath` package that defines `pmatrix` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : it must be included automatically, doesn't it?

Comment: I have no idea about lyx but your output suggests pmatrix environment is not defined and you are getting the `\pmatrix` command (inherited from plain TeX) which is just taking the 0 as argument

Comment: LyX doesn't load `amsmath` automatically unless you use some of its features via the menus/toolbars in LyX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare your expression with and without `amsmath`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$u_{L}(k) = \sqrt{E}\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! The package "AMS Math" wasn't enabled in the document's options.